# React Native uninitialized dimensions

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My react native app crashes some times and results uninitialized dimensions like the one shown in the image.
I use bootsplash for my splash screen and i suspect that it is causing the problem.
[Everything just shrinks sometimes not always](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsBR.jpg)

Comment: Please post a minimal, reproducible example of your code.

Comment: But i don't know which part of the code is causing this